Approximation of Lipschitz functions by convex combinaison of Lipschitz functions depending on projections
Let $K\subset \mathbb R^2$ be compact. For any $c>0$, denote by ${\rm Lip}_c(K)$ the collection of Lipschitz functions $f:K\to\mathbb R$ whose Lipschitz constant is less than or equal to $c$. Set  ${\rm Lip}(K):=\cup_{c>0}{\rm Lip}_c(K)$.
Let $S^1\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the unit sphere, i.e. $(x,y)\in S^1$ if and only if $x^2+y^2=1$. Define, for every $n\ge 1$, $F_n\subset {\rm Lip}(K)$ to be the subset consisting of elements $f$ so that
$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{1\le k\le m} a_k \phi_k(u_kx+v_ky),$$
where $m\in\mathbb N$,  $a_1,\ldots, a_m\ge 0$, $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_m: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are $1-$Lipschitz, $(u_1,v_1),\ldots, (u_m,v_m)\in S^1$ and
$$\sum_{1\le k\le m} a_k\le n.$$
Put $F:=\cup_{n\ge 1}F_n$.
Under which topology (e.g. uniform topology or $L^1$ norm) $F$ is dense in ${\rm Lip}(K)$? Under which topology there exists $N$ such that $F_N$ is dense in ${\rm Lip}_1(K)$?
